# Div picture cut out of div box

Tags: css, html

I was just adapting a webdesign, when I found a problem and couldn't slove it on my own.

I coded a heading and an article picture, both in the same div, with a border at the bottom of the div. 
My problem: The border comes right after the title and doesn't integrate my picture.

**Check out this fiddle to see what i mean: [Click me!](http://jsfiddle.net/JannikS/WEHw4/1/)**

Here is my code:

```
<div class="latestarticle">   
<a class="articletitle" href="#" >Guitar Hero Experts Melt Your Face Off</a> 
<div class="articlepicture">
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.latestarticle { 
border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 12px;
font-size: 12px; 
} 

.articletitle {   
color: #CD5700;
text-decoration: none; 
font-weight: bold; 
font-size: 14px;  
margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
.articlepicture {
height: 76px;
width: 136px;
float: left;
margin-top: 12px;
margin-right: 9px;
border: solid #A3A3A3 2px;
}
```

Comment: use float:left on your latestarticle div. This should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering why this is not working. This should work, anyway, add `display: table;` or `display: table-cell;` to your `.latestarticle`. It works fine. See **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WEHw4/6/)**

**Edit**

Oh! I came to know this problem is happening because you have floated left to your `.articlepicture` and I hope you wanted to do as demo.

I have added `<div class="articlegroup"></div>` for your `.articlepicture` div and defined it `display: inline-block;`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WEHw4/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

use css `display: block` to **.articletitle**

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a clearfix.  You need to add a "clearfix" div as a sibling to a floated element if you want the parent to recognize the height of the floated element.

```
<div class="latestarticle">   
  <a class="articletitle" href="#">Guitar Hero</a> 
  <div class="articlepicture"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Then define the .clearfix style in css:

```
.clearfix { clear:both; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `disply:inline-block;`  for latestarticle .see here  http://jsfiddle.net/WEHw4/5/